# I can't access a webpage through python requests module but I can access the website from my PC browser

Tags: web-scraping, python-requests

I am trying to access this website **https://99acres.com** with python requests module but it just keeps processing and does not stop while the same website works fine on browser.
After 10 min it gives an error
`ConnectionError: ('Connection aborted.', ConnectionResetError(10054, 'An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host', None, 10054, None))`

Following  is my code:

```
import requests
url = 'https://99acres.com'
headers = { 
'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:121.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/121.0'
}
r = requests.get(url,headers = headers)
```

I have tried the following:

- giving user-agent in headers.
- copying the request from the browser inspect as Curl and then converted it to python from online website.
  Unfortunately nothing seems to work.

Is it possible to connect with this website from python request module?

Comment: Where does the python script runs? On your computer where you can access the website via browser? Have you tried to access the site via `curl`? My guess into the wild is, that outbound connections are dropped from where you run that python script. Have you tried you python script with a other domain, e.g. `https://example.com`?

Comment: Yes, code runs on the same computer .I am using vs code as the editor.I have tried other websites e.g. https://cardekho.com and it works ,in just 0.1s it connects.Also I have also tried to use online websites like postman to send GET request to this url (htts://99acres.com).The GET request fails every time.

Answer (score 0):

You've tried the obvious and it doesn't work, so what could it be?

One reason could be that the website relies on javascript being present. If that is the case, you could still access that data, but not through `requests`. Use something like selenium or other tool that pretends to be a browser and has a javascript runtime environment.

It could also be that the site really doesn't want to be scrapped. If that is the case, they would have implemented some measures to test that you are a real user coming from a browser, in which case things are a lot trickier.

Comment: `One reason could be that the website relies on javascript being present` If so, you would still get (at least header and) body from the webserver back. More likely that outbound requests from where the python script is hosted are blocked.

Comment: @Marc I think that is highly unlikely. I think it's much more likely to be my 2nd point. I got curious and looked at the site. It's some real estate site and might have some incentive in preventing scrapping. I tested with `curl` and got the same behavior as OP, the remote host drops the connection.

Comment: @wombat Yes, using selenium I can connect to this site and I have a working code also.But as I need the json response so I am looking for connecting via python request module.

Comment: @Manjushri Seems unlikely to me you will have any success without something like Selenium. Let's pretend for a second that the host wasn't blocking you, what would you even be able to get with `requests`? You can see this by disabling javascript in the dev tools in Chrome, which would be similar to what requests gets if it got a response.

Comment: @wombat Actually I have isolated an API url of this site that fetches a json file.This file has  details of 25 properties and I need to get the details of 4000 properties so the no. of pages are 160.Now through selenium I am able to get the required details but it consumes time.If I get the json response through python request module  then my job will be much easier. I have done this with other sites and there I didn't got any problems.